# how to find how many days each item stayed in each category

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

My dataset looks something like this:

```
Item | Date        | Category
1    | 01/01/2019  | A
1    | 02/01/2019  | A
1    | 03/01/2019  | B
2    | 10/02/2019  | A
2    | 11/02/2019  | B
2    | 12/02/2019  | B
2    | 13/01/2019  | C
3    | 07/02/2019  | A
3    | 10/02/2019  | A
```

So, this is basically a panel dataset, because for each item there are many dates, but they are not necessarily continued (see item 3). When an item dissapears it means it was sold. Also items' codes will not be repeated, so item 1 only references that item. The "date" is in string format.
This is just a sample but the dataset has millions of rows.

My goal is to find descriptive statistics, and I'm specially interested in getting the average days an item spends in each category.

Tried using

```
df.groupby(category).mean()
```

but i find it's not really giving me what I'm looking for. Any ideas?

Comment: This question is pretty broad.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can try `groupby` with`nunique` to get the number of unique date per item and category

```
print (df.groupby(['Item', 'Category'])['Date'].nunique()
Item  Category
1     A           2
      B           1
2     A           1
      B           2
      C           1
3     A           2
Name: Date, dtype: int64
```

followed by `unstack` to make it with a different shape.

```
print (df.groupby(['Item', 'Category'])['Date'].nunique().unstack(fill_value=0))
Category  A  B  C
Item             
1         2  1  0
2         1  2  1
3         2  0  0
```

which is then equivalent to a `pivot_table`:

```
df.pivot_table(index='Item', columns='Category', values='Date', 
               aggfunc='nunique', fill_value=0)
```